# Accessing to base class of derived class by derived class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

The function `whoAmI()` is supposed to return:

```
I am a Man
I am a Omnivore
```

But it just returns `"I am a Man"` twice:

```
class Animal
{
public:
  string className;
};

class Omnivore:public Animal
{
 public:
    Omnivore()
    {
        className = "Omnivore";
    }
};

class Man:public Omnivore
{
public:
    Man() {
        className = "Man";
    }
     void whoAmI()
     {
         cout << "I am a " << Omnivore::className << endl;
         cout << "I am a " << Omnivore::Animal::className << endl;
     }
};
```

Comment: There is only one `className` for a given `this`, regardless of how you refer to it.

Comment: Because `Omnivore::className` and `Omnivore::Animal::className` are two names for one string variable - one variable cannot have two values at the same time

Comment: Make `className` a (virtual or static) function, then it will work.

Comment: Check out the [Definitive C++ Book Guide/List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2069064).

Comment: You cannot override data members.

Comment: Also, `whoAmI()` doesn't *return* anything - it's `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one `Animal::className`, which is initialized to empty `std::string` by `Animal`'s constructor, then assigned to `"Omnivore"` by `Omnivore`'s constructor, then assigned to `Man` by `Man`'s constructor. So you got the same results, because they refer to same data member.

You can make them have their own data member with the same name; but note that it's not a good idea, the names in derived class will *hide* those in base class. e.g.

```
class Animal
{
public:
  string className;
};

class Omnivore:public Animal
{
 public:
    string className;
    Omnivore()
    {
        className = "Omnivore";
    }
};

class Man:public Omnivore
{
public:
    string className;
    Man() {
        className = "Man";
    }
     void whoAmI()
     {
         cout << "I am a " << Omnivore::className << endl;         // "Omnivore"
         cout << "I am a " << Omnivore::Animal::className << endl; // empty
         cout << "I am a " << className << endl;                   // "Man"
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually done this way:

```
class Animal
{
public:
  static string className() { return "Man"; };
};

class Omnivore:public Animal
{
public:
  static string className() { return "Omnivore"; };
  void whoAmI()
  {
      cout << "I am a " << Omnivore::className() << endl;
      cout << "I am a " << Animal::className() << endl;
  }
};
```